# PHP version not equal to Homebrew's on OSX

Tags: php

I'm using OSX, I just installed php71 using

```
brew install php71
```

when I run

```
php -v
```

I get the correct php version. However if I unlink php71 using

```
brew unlink php71
```

And i run

```
php -v
```

**I still see that php71 is installed.**

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm trying to get php56 to be the current one.

Comment: The easiest way is to close the Terminal window and open another one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rehash your shell's lookups of programs after installing or uninstalling anything. Under `bash` use:

```
hash -r
```

Then try to see if your PATH is correct, or you have any aliases set up with:

```
type php
```

If that tells you an answer including the word `alias`, you have an alias set up and should  unset it with:

```
unalias php
```

If it tells you anything beginning with:

```
/usr/local/...anything.../php
```

it means you still have a **homebrew** PHP at that location. If you want to use the Apple-supplied PHP, make sure `/usr/local/bin` is near the right-hand end of your PATH and that `/usr/bin` is nearer the left-hand end of your PATH.

If it tells you anything beginning with:

```
/usr/bin
```

it means you are running an Apple-supplied PHP. If you want to run a **homebrew** PHP instead, make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is near the start (left-hand end) of your PATH.